# Can I rename a Vagrant box?

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

I misspelled the name of a box when I added it to my box list:

```
vagrant box list
debian
ubnutu
```

Can I rename the box without repackaging it?

Answer (score 48):

You can simply rename the dir that represents the box. If your vagrant files are in their default dir (i.e. /path/to/your/home/.vagrant.d) you can just do:

```
mv vagrant_path/boxes/box_to_rename vagrant_path/boxes/new_box_name
```

Also be sure to change the Vagrantfile to use the new label for the box. You just need to change the `config.vm.box` directive to reflect the changes.

Comment: This didn't work for me - I suspect there is a config file somewhere that needs to be updated as well. @Till's suggestion worked.

Comment: @AdrianMouat: Hmm, worked for me.  Did you have VMs actively running with the box in question at the time of the rename?  I could imagine that maybe causing problems, though I don't really know that or why it would, necessarily.  What results did you get when you tried?

Comment: @lindes-hw I've no idea, it was 10 months ago...

Comment: @AdrianMouat: fair enough.  Mostly, I just wanted to not have that comment left there un-responded-to, as it detracts (to my mind) from the idea of this being a correct answer, and yet, I think it is.  If there are real problems with it, though, it would be good to hear about them - whether from you, or someone else who encounters them in the future.

Comment: @lindes-hw It might be relevant that I was running on Mac OS. I don't believe I had actively running VMs at the time; I think I would have checked that.

Comment: OK, well my test just now was also on MacOS.  So I don't know...

Comment: On Linux, the box would typically be in ~/.vagrant.d/boxes. So you can do `mv ~/.vagrant.d/boxes/<badname> ~/.vagrant.d/boxes/<goodname>`
EDIT: Sorry, didn't catch the note in the parenthesis, I will leave the duplicate here anyway, since it is visually clearer for me and maybe others as well.

Answer (score 13):

I would do this:

```
$ vagrant box repackage misspelled-name
[vagrant] Compressing package to: /Users/johndoe/package.box
$ vagrant box add correct-name /Users/johndoe/package.box
...
```

Not the worst to know about these two anyway, since you can frequently update base boxes (e.g. to update the kernel, software and guest additions) to avoid running all these required updates every time you `vagrant up`.

Comment: Is it okay to delete the package.box file when this is done?

Comment: @PeterHanley Yep. Once imported, it's ok to get rid off it.

Comment: Note that this will take much longer than simply renaming the underlying file, and does lots of extra work that's probably not necessary in most (all?) cases.

Comment: @lindes-hw can you show a better way? And why?

Answer (score 0):

On windows, you can rename the box folder name here.
C:\Users\uday.vagrant.d\boxes\

It will update automatically